# Deriving $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{π^2}{6}-ψ^{(1)}(n+1)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How is the partial sums formula of the $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{π^2}{6}-ψ^{(1)}(n+1)$$
derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown with the [Hurwitz Zeta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11) (see especially formulas  [(1)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E1) and [(2)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E12))

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} 
= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} - \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} \\
= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i+n+1)^2} \\
= \zeta(2)-\zeta(2,n+1)\\
=  \frac{\pi^2}{6}-ψ^{(1)}(n+1)$$
and the well known value $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for the Riemann Zeta function.

Answer (score 2):

Check this article on the Trigamma function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function. The series formula can by obtained by deriving the series for the Digamma function (presumably obtained by the residues theorem).